# Нагрузка на процессор

Tags: jquery, comet, php

Добрый день. Не очень разбираюсь в этом деле, но написал два приложения на технологии `Comet`. Одно работает на всех страницах после входа и никакой проблемы, никакой нагрузки, а вот второе приложение работает только на одной странице и при переходе на эту страницу нагрузка на процессор выскакивает на 100%, и компьютер тормозит, не могу понять в чём дело. Во втором приложение запрос с базы чуть-чуть по сложнее, но я не думаю, что это из за этого. Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чём проблема или как можно ее выявить? Большое спасибо.

PHP код

```
$limit = 360;
$time = time();

$i = $_POST['i'];
$you = $_POST['you'];
set_time_limit($limit+5);
// Здесь подключаюсь к базе

while (time() - $time < $limit) {     
    $res = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
    message_id, message_sender, message_receiver, message_text, message_date 
    FROM message WHERE 
    message_status=0 AND
    (message_receiver='$i' OR message_sender='$i') AND 
    (message_receiver='$you' OR message_sender='$you') 
    ORDER BY message_date DESC");
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while ($cm=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            echo '
            <div class="chatMesBody">
                <div class="message_id'.$cm['message_id'].'">
                    <div class="chatMesAuthor">
                        <a href="#">'.$cm['message_sender'].'</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chatMesText">
                        '.$cm['message_text'].'
                    </div>
                    <div class="chatMesConf">
                        '.$cm['message_date'].'
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>';
            flush();
            $sqlUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE message SET message_status=1 WHERE message_id=$cm[message_id]");
        }
        sleep(5);
        exit;
    }
}
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас есть бесконечный цикл или плохо написанный запрос к БД)
Без кода - сложно судить.

Так-же, как вариант - у вас активное ожидание данных.

**UPD:**
Как я и думал - у вас активное ожидание на появление данных в БД:

```
while (time() - $time < $limit) {
    ...
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
      ...
      sleep(5);
      exit;
    }
}
```

Надо как-то так:

```
while (time() - $time < $limit) {
    ...
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
      ...
      // убрать sleep(5); и exit;
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: Да можно сказать и так но и впервом и во втором случае одно и тоже но нагрузка только во втором случаее вот это я не могу понять код вылажу как только приду домой

Comment: Да вы были правы большое спасибо вам

Comment: Примите ответ